# Validate multiple fields using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have to validate multiple fields and if any field is having `error` then I should disable the submit button. This code working like (out of two fields if one field is not having any error) then the button is enabled which should not be happened.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#EmpCode #LoginUser').keyup(function() {
    $('#ecode').html('Checking availability...');
    var empc = $('#EmpCode').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/Admin/Employee/IsEmpCodeExists',
      method: 'post',
      data: {
        employeecode: empc
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == 1) {
          $('#ecode').html('<font color = "red">Employee Code already Exits..</font>');
          $('#addEmployee').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
          $('#ecode').html('');
          $('#addEmployee').attr('disabled', false);
        }
      },
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#LoginUser').on('change keyup', function() {
    $('#lusername').html('Checking availability...');
    var lu = $('#LoginUser').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/Admin/Employee/IsUserNameExists',
      method: 'post',
      data: {
        uname: lu
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == 1) {
          $('#lusername').html('<font color = "red">User Name already Exits..</font>');
          $('.addEmployee').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
          $('#lusername').html('');
          $('.addEmployee').attr('disabled', false);
        }
      },
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addEmployee" value="Add Employee" name="Add Employee">
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's not the way you validate the form. You don't have to rewrite `$document.ready` every time and it would be better to send the whole form to validation instead of every single field. The other thing is that submit button should be disabled by default.

But if you really need to do this the way you want, do something like this (add a class `.to-validate` to every input you are validating, and:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#EmpCode #LoginUser').keyup(function() {
    var xthis = this;
    $('#ecode').html('Checking availability...');
    var empc = $('#EmpCode').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/Admin/Employee/IsEmpCodeExists',
      method: 'post',
      data: {
        employeecode: empc
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == 1) {
          $(xthis).removeClass('valid');
        } else {
          $(xthis).addClass('valid');
          if($('.to-validate').length == $('.valid').length)
             $('.addEmployee').prop('disabled', false);
          else
             $('.addEmployee').prop('disabled', true);
        }
      },
    });
  });

  etc ...

});
```